# ScrollView for only a portion of the Screen

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm having some trouble dividing my screen up in to two parts. I don't know where to begin actually. All of my layouts thus far have been using RelativeLayout. Basically, I want to have a scrollable view in the top 70%(or so) of the screen, and two buttons in the bottom 30%(or so) of the screen. The scrollview would be filled with several textViews. Here's my barebone code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/stonerepeat"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>








<Button
android:id="@+id/back"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Looks good"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/stats"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hero Stats"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/back"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/back" 
android:layout_above="@+id/back"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
>
</Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can nest layouts. So what you need to do is have two second-level layouts where one of them will scroll its contents, and another one, fixed, will be attached to the bottom and will hold just buttons. Then you need to play with properties until you get proper result.

Comment: should i nest relative or linear layouts? I'm not sure how I would keep them from overlapping. buttons on top of the lowered of the scrollview or the scrollview completely hiding the buttons

Comment: there's more than one way to skin a cat. What I wanted to say is that you need to experiment yourself in order to understand how that layout stuff works (and it's very powerful). Without understanding you can get a solution from someone, but you won't be able to modify or re-imlement it in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want percentages, the easiest way is to use a `LinearLayout` and weights. Something like:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>
    <ScrollView android:layout_weight="7" ... />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_weight="3" ...>
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```